# Cannot receive packets specified to my IP address

Tags: c#, network-programming

I have an application which sends broadcast messages on a specific port and listens for an answer on a LAN. According to a wireshark session, some devices will answer to the ip address (for example) 192.168.1.255 while others will respond to my specific ip address (again, for example) 192.168.10.13

The problem I have is that my application will see the responses from the devices sending their answers on the broadcast ip address (192.168.10.255) but my application cannot see the responses targeted at my ip address.

Here is how I set up and send packets

```
public struct UdpState
{
    public System.Net.IPEndPoint EP;
    public System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient UDPClient;
}

public static void StartTimers()
{
    //setting up "GlobalUdp" as a UdpClient, with an endpoint of the NIC selected and the port 30303
    //making the endpoint the ip address of the NIC
    System.Net.IPEndPoint BindEP = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(Properties.Settings.Default.selectedNic), 30303);
    GlobalUdp.UDPClient = new UdpClient(BindEP); //binding to that NIC and port
    GlobalUdp.EP = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255"), 30303);
    GlobalUdp.UDPClient.EnableBroadcast = true;
    GlobalUdp.UDPClient.MulticastLoopback = false;       
}

public static void SendBroadcast(object source, ElapsedEventArgs f)
{
    byte[] DiscoverMsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Discovery: Who is out there?"); //this has to be the message sent for devices to reply
    GlobalUdp.UDPClient.Send(DiscoverMsg, DiscoverMsg.Length, new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255"), 30303)); //sending the message
}
```

And here is how I listen for packets

```
public static void WaitingForMessages()
{
    UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(30303); //creating a UDPClient that will listen on port 30303
    IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 30303); //making the endpoit listen to any IP Address on port 30303
    string received_data; //this string will hold data about the ansering device
    byte[] receive_byte_array; //this array will hold all the data about the device in an order fashion
    while (Properties.Settings.Default.keepListening) //while the user setting that controls listening is set to true
    {
        try
        {
            receive_byte_array = listener.Receive(ref groupEP); //getting the data from the listener
            received_data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receive_byte_array, 0, receive_byte_array.Length); //getting the data
            string[] messageComponents = received_data.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None); //splitting the data into an array
            List<string> deviceCompenentsList = new List<string>(messageComponents); //creating a list from that array
            deviceCompenentsList.Add(groupEP.Address.ToString()); //adding the IP Address of the device to the list
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); //for troubleshooting
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Exiting listening"); //for troubleshooting
    listener.Close(); //close the listener
    listener.Dispose();
}
```

The application is set up to bind to a NIC, start listening, and then send broadcast messages on a timer (30 seconds).

Why doesn't my application receive the messages going to my ip address?

Comment: Are you seeing the message using wireshark on your computer?  The message may not be getting to you PC.  The Broadcast message at 255 may be getting swallowed by another application on you PC.  So you may need to handle as a group.

Comment: I am using wireshark on my computer. Once my application starts, it binds to the NIC so another application that requires sending messages on the same NIC will be stopped while my application is running.

Comment: The IP addresses are event coming from the ethernet card towards the applications.  As the starts PC each service/application registers for the IP port number and doesn't normally forward the port to the next registered event.  So first that mask on the ethernet interface (use cmd.exe IPConfig/ALL) must allow the IP address to reach the applications.  So the last mask number should be zero.  The Broadcast (255) messages are usually handle at the Gateway PC in the subnet having address X.X.X.1 (but can be any IP).

Comment: My pc is within the same subnet as the default gateway and the rest of the devices. It is a /24 network (255.255.255.0 mask). All the communication are on this /24 network. But the messages going to the gateway will come to my pc, what is the difference between going to the default gateway first rather than answer to my pc right away?

Comment: There shouldn't be any differences.  Just most protocols have the gateway handle the broadcast.  If you are not using a standard protocol then it probably doesn't make a difference.  I'm just concerned that another app on the PC isn't blocking the Broadcast address 255.

Comment: Ok, I am using UDP to send and receive messages. I'm just confused why I can get the broadcast back but not the message going right to my PC.

Comment: Can you send broadcast?  I think you are going to need to use the same socket for sending and receiving the broadcast.  It lloks like you are calling the constructor twice.  Once in StartTimers and the other in WaitingForMessages

Comment: I can send broadcast messages and receive the replies as long as the reply is to x.x.x.255

Comment: With a 24 bit mask you cannot receive 255.255.255.255.  Normally the rule is to set the mask on port going towards the INTERNET with a mask of 0.0.0.0.  So al none Gateways on the subnet with have 0.0.0.0.  The Gateway that has two Ethernet Port the one towards the INTERNET has 0.0.0.0., and second that is in the subnet will have a smaller mask.  You never want to have two masks on the same PC with the same length subnet.  This way the getway only sends IP in the subnet to the subnet and everything else defaults to the back-bone.  It also will prevent routing loops.

Comment: I can communicate with all the devices on the network, the problem comes when a device is trying to reach the application. If a device answers to the local broadcast ,192.168.10.255, it will make it.

Comment: So where is it not making the broadcast?  Routers and Servers will not forward broadcast messages unless specially configured.